Mac wifi on android hotspot connected but no internet
Internet is working fine on my phone which is using 4G. I'm using the same phone to create a hotspot which I'm connecting to from my Macbook and another android. The hotspot connection works on android but on mac there is no internet even though wifi shows that it is connected and has internet access.
The only solution I found on the internet was to try renewing DHCP lease from mac wifi settings which I did but problem did not resolve.

Is the Mac able to get an IP address via DHCP?

Yes the IP address is shown in the settings

I tried changing the DNS settings of the hotspot wifi on my mac from 1.1.1.1 to 8.8.8.8 and that fixed the problem.
